# remove the "NaN" in the string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

anyone knows how to remove the "NaN" on the string?

I just do:

```
if(!$request->captcha_token){
    return "Ops! hold your horse cowboy! please tell me that your not a robot. Fill the captcha!";
    exit;
}
```

and in my ajax success function I just did

```
success: function (data) {
    this_current.parents(".modal-content").find("#error_container").fadeIn(200);
    this_current.parents(".modal-content").find("#error_container").html(
        '<div class="alert alert-danger overflow_auto" role="alert">' + '<span class="extend display_block align_left margin_right7px"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i></span>' + +'<span class="align_left display_block">' + data + '</span></div>');
}
```

but the respond string always has NaN like

> NaNOps! hold your horse cowboy! please tell me that your not a robot. Fill the captcha!

I tried to remove it using

```
data.replace('NaN', '')
```

but unfortunately it doesnt work, any help?

Comment: you seem to have neglected to show how exactly `data` is assigned a value

Comment: this should work if data holds  "NaNOps! hold your horse cowboy! please tell me that your not a robot. Fill the captcha!" but data is not holding that string directly.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: Re-write `html( '' + '' + + '' + data + '');` properly. Unary `+` here converts an empty string to `NaN`.

Comment: thank you guys, its fixed now!

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic because "a simple typographical error"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN value is Occurring when you apply wrong parsing.

Like: 
**parseFloat("geoff")**

it will give you NaN for check this value you can use

**isNaN(parseFloat("geoff"))**

and Inside your code i think error in this line its not related to data. error in your code:

here you are putting:

```
 "<span>"+ +"</span><span>"+data+"</span>";
```

here between the + operator there is no variable.

try this :

```
"<span>"+data+"</span>";
```

if it's not working then you can apply condition on your reponse data you can check NaN value by this:

```
if(isNaN(data)){ return " ";}
```

Comment: easier to only process valid data, `if (!isNaN(data)) {doSomething();}`